# Update Database in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

I have the problem while updating database, it throws error connection is closed. I can't find where the problem is. I have started `connection.open` but it is not working.

```
public void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtName.Text != "" && txtRollNo.Text != "" && txtRegdNo.Text != "" && txtProgram.Text != "" && txtValidity.Text != "" && pBoxPhoto.Image != null && pBoxQR.Image != null)
    {
        scommand = new SqlCommand("update tblRegistration set name=@name,rollno=@rollno,regdno=@regdno,program=@program,address=@address, validity=@validity where ID=@id", connection);

        scommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txtID.Text);
        scommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtName.Text);
        scommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@program", txtProgram.Text);
        scommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@regdno", txtRegdNo.Text);
        scommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rollno", txtRollNo.Text);
        scommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@validity", txtValidity.Text);
        scommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", txtAddress.Text);

        connection.Open();
        sCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show("Record Updated Successfully");
        clearData();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
        fillData();

        connection.Close();
        clickable();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Provide Details!");
    }
}
```

Please guide me where I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

[image: Error Message]

Comment: You should be using a new connection each time, not trying to reuse the same one.  If you use a DataTable and DataAdapter you wouldnt have to beat the DGV up with `dataGridView1.DataSource = null;` just update the source

Comment: use using statement to take of disposing the connection

Comment: 1. Your database connection is not open. 2. You need to include the parameter values with their native type. If id is an integer in the database then add the value using a .net int / Int32. 3. Create and dispose of ado.net types as you need them with `using` statements, do not share these instances across methods/classes. Please see [Best Practices - Executing Sql Statements](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/.net/3589/ado-net/14261/best-practices-executing-sql-statements)

Comment: keep a debug point and run

Answer (score 0):

SqlConnection Class implements IDisposable, therefore the neatest way to use it is:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection())
{
   // perform Sql Command using the connection
}
```

when exiting from the scope, since you used `using`, the Dispose method is automatically called (Dispose is equivalent to Close for that class).

Comment: i am getting new error, An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in QRCARD.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: there are different constructors for `SqlConnection`, so use the same you were using before (for example  `new SqlConnection("my fancy SQL connection..");`

Comment: sorry i am not getting you :-(

Comment: Please use Visual Studio debugger to let me know where that exception is happening.

Comment: error is at scommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtName.Text);

Comment: the only two objects which can be null are `scommand` or `txtName`. Are you still using `scommand = new SqlCommand("update tblRegistration ...`) before line `scommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtName.Text);`